# Is a rotor of an electrical motor charged with electricity?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, electromagnetism, solenoid

This might seem to be dumb question, but as far as I understand it:

An electrical motor is made of a rotor and a stator.
The stator is electrically powered: it has a solenoid and current passing into it.
This creates both a E and B (electrical and magnetic) fields.

Then those fields triggers a Lorentz force on the rotor, depending of:

- E -> OK
- B -> OK
- current speed v of the rotor -> OK
- the electrical charge q

I am wondering:

- Is it the electrical charge q of the rotor or the stator?
- Is it a charge induced on the rotor by the electrical field created by the stator?
- What is the link between the solenoid in the rotor and the solenoid of the stator?

For context:
I am trying to calculate the solenoid caracteristics (L) of the stator, possible resistance and capacity caracteristics (of the circuit on the stator), and the solenoids characteristics of the rotor (do I really need it?). All these characteristics should help me to design the input (current and voltage of the stator) and the ouput (rotationnal torque and speed of the rotor), but it seems I need also to power with electricity the rotor.

EDIT:
To answer the different comments: 1/ I want a rotating motor, powered with DC current. I want to achieve at the output some torque and rotationnal speed 2/ @Transistor If we are interested in the current I, is it the current in the rotor or the stator 3/ If I choose a static magnet for the rotor, and an electomagnet for the stator, I don't need to provide current in the rotor (I mean: no battery in the rotor?) 4/ Is a solenoid a possible solution for electromagnet?

Comment: It's not charge we're interested in - it's the movement of charge per unit time - and that's the definition of current. \$ I = \frac {dQ}{dt}\$.

Comment: A Capacitor stores electric charges and a Magnetic stores magnetic charges.  The Stator coil can create a torque by producing an electromagnetic flux to interact with the rotor flux. The math https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force

Comment: which type of motor are you considering?

Comment: I think you are misusing the term solenoid as it sounds like you are interested in rotating motor not a linear actuator.  motors are pretty simple its just chasing magnets.  often one side is a static magnet the other side is an electromagnet, you can have the rotor be static and the stator be an electromagnet, dont need brushes in that case. or you can have the rotor have an eletromagnet and the stator be fixed magnets.  and then it is just a matter of timing the direction and amount of current through the coils.

Comment: Are you wanting to know about an AC motor, DC, a stepper, what kind of stepper, etc.  And for lack of a better term the architecture of the motor in question.

Comment: To answer the different comments:
1/ I want a rotating motor, powered with DC current. I want to achieve at the output some torque and rotationnal speed
2/ @Transistor If we are interested in the current I, is it the current in the rotor or the stator
3/ If I choose a static magnet for the rotor, and an electomagnet for the stator, I don't need to provide current in the rotor (I mean: no battery in the rotor?)
4/ Is a solenoid a possible solution for electromagnet?

Comment: So @Transistor when you speak of I = dQ/dt, ok. But should I consider for the lorentz force the current in the rotor or in the stator?

Comment: If it is a DC motor, then you have to know if it uses Permanent Magnets on the rotor, or if it uses commutation brushes to feed power to windings, in which case it is then called an "armature". In either case the part of your question relating to induced voltages does not apply, you are mixing AC induction motor concepts in with your question about DC motors.

Comment: @JRaef Not sure to understand everything, but I am correct if I say: Considering a DC motor with an aluminium rotor (no coil, no magnet), and no commutation brushes, then the aluminium rotor has no current in itself? And I should consider the I of the stator to calculate the Lorentz force = q * speed * MagneticField?